# date function in while loop of php

Tags: php

I want to use date() function in while loop of PHP but I'm getting an error as

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 500 seconds exceeded.

I tried to set the execution time more than the time required for the loop to complete, yet it isn't working as expected.

```
<?php
 ini_set('max_execution_time',500);

 print date("H:i");

 while(date("H:i")!="16:50"){

 $i=0;
 }

if(date("H:i")=="16:50"){

$file = "buttonStatus.txt";
$handle = fopen($file,'w+');
$onstring = "ON";
fwrite($handle,$onstring);
fclose($handle);

$i=1;
} 

echo $i;
?>
```

Comment: It's probably very good you have a max_execution_limit since this will likely max out your CPU for the entire day until 16:50.

Comment: It would sound like you should use a CRON job for this - a PHP file that's constantly running like this is not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
while(date("H:i")!="16:50"){
   $i=0;
}
```

Does nothing but create an infinite loop, there is no way to exit it unless the time reaches the set time. It will literally just loop constantly and never reach the code below it.

If you want to run this script at 16:50 everyday you would be better using a cron task/job. A cron is a task that is run repeatedly, it could be every few minutes, every week, month.. whatever you need.

If you can explain what you are trying to achieve here I can give you a better solution.

Comment: Actually, the time difference between current time and "16:50",while I was executing the code, was of 2 minutes. Which means there came a point when condition in while loop was true. Yet it didnt work.

Comment: I want to write some text in a file after certain interval of time.

Comment: @Shruti, so why not just sleep the number of seconds you want to wait?  Not really sure the use case here, but it's much better than using a while loop like this.

Comment: Your computer can run millions of lines of code in a second. when the time is actually 16:50, the while loop will still run ALOT of times. the code isn't optimal